# Jquery Show Value on Left Panel when Right Panel li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to populate values on the left Panel DIV which is hidden when LI on the Right Panel is clicked. My format might not work, I don't know. Is there any way to achieve this task.

```
 <div class="left-main" style="float:left;padding-right:25px;border-right:2px solid black;padding:25px;">
<h1>This is Left Filter</h1>


<div class="left" style="display:none;">

    <ul >
    <li id="one">Content 1</li>
    <li id="two">Content 2</li>
    <li id="three">Content 3</li>
    <li id="four">Content 4</li>
   <li id="five">Content 5</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="right">
    <ul>
        <li class="one">Content 1</a></li>
        <li class="two">Content 2</a></li>
        <li class="three">Content 3</li>
        <li class="four">Content 4</li>
        <li class="five">Content 5</li>
    </ul>
```

Here is an example in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8Aqvb/3/
any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Question is not clear. rephrasing needed.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. I just did the following:

[**JSFiddle Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/FJSZX/)

(1) I added `cursor:pointer;` to what I'll call your 'navigation,' so that it looks like you're actually clicking and expecting something to happen.

```
.right ul li {
  display:inline;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

(2) I changed the first link of your jQuery code to work with the elements in what I'll call your "content" rather than the entire divider your content is located in. I placed an id for the unordered list based on whether its purpose is for navigation or for showing content, which is also how I'll refer to the two. Feel free to modify the id and class names as you like, but when you polish up the code, keep it consistent!

`$("#content li").hide();`

(3) Classes are shared between the content items. You can use ids or classes - you just need to identify the link between each one (Content 1 maps to Content 1, etc.) Depending on what the placeholders are for, you may want to use whatever appropriate names for the ids or classes.

(4) Hiding and showing content is simple - once someone clicks one of the five items in the navigation, we'll hide everything as if we just loaded the page. This will prevent more than one content item from appearing at once. We'll replace them as the end user clicks by. After everything is hidden once more, or in other words, after the current content item being displayed is hidden again, we'll show the one that the end user just clicked by using the class name to map to the right list item in the content. (Content 1 maps to Content 1, etc.)

The reason for the split is just to ensure we get the first class name. If you ever want to add more classes for a particular item, just leave the class reserved for linking to the content item as first. So if you want to make your content item background red and you create and add in a red class, you can do something like `class="one red";` and `split(" ")[0]` will ensure it only gets 'one,' which is what we're using to map to the right content item.

```
$( "#nav li" ).click(function(e) {
  $("#content li").hide();
  $("#content li." + e.target.className.split(" ")[0]).show();
});
```

- Note: You have an extra  lying in your html. Not sure how your entire html looks like, so I'll leave it to you to polish the code up. Let me know if you have another approach in mind rather than getting the id or class to show and hide the right elements.

Comment: Thanks, That was exactly what I needed. awesome!! You saved My day. This was just a test site and the HTML is not clear yet. But you did answer the functionality that I needed for this application. Thank you so much..

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Depending on how you do work out the HTML and CSS in your site, you may not need to resort to something like getting the element's class.

Comment: And thank you for explaining so briefly. I will keep that in mind definitely. Thanks.